# Is it possible to detect whether or not wmode is supported on a user's Flash Player?

Tags: html, flash, swfobject, wmode

I am currently experiencing an issue with a website where we are using a SWF for the background. However, it has been determined that when viewing the website on one particular Android device, the SWF's layering is disregarded, and is being forced to the top.

After some research I discovered that this was most likely to do with the following note from the Official Adobe website:

> Note: The WMODE parameter is supported only on some browser/Flash Player version combinations. If the WMODE parameter is not supported, the SWF files always displays on top. See Create a transparent background in a SWF file for more information

Source: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/swf-file-ignores-stacking-order.html

So I was wondering whether or not it would be possible to detect whether a user's Flash Player would support the WMODE parameter and if not then I could hide the SWF from displaying?

Comment: You can use Javascript to detect the browser, and Actionscript to [detect the OS and Flash Player version the SWF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) is running on. But waiting to find that out info in Actionscript may be too late (b/c the page is already rendered and the SWF is running). Theoretically, you could make your SWF run (but not show the UI) for the sole purpose of detecting the OS/version ... and then use ExternalInterface and Javascript to rearrange the DOM. Ideally you figure that out w/JS before the SWF is embedded.

Comment: I fear that merely detecting the OS/Flash Player version might not be enough. There appears to be no list (that I've found anyway) that indicates exactly which browser/flash player version's do not support WMODE. So although I could create a workaround for this specific Android device, there is no telling what other devices/browsers/flash players will be affected by the same issue.